# SignalR Invocation was canceled

Tags: java, android, proguard, okhttp, signalr.client

I'm using signalR core java client in an android application. It work fine before enable minify but after enable it signalR connect to server but just in first invoke I got this error:

```
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Invocation was canceled.
        at b.e.a.Y.a(InvocationRequest.java:43)
        at b.e.a.M$a.a(HubConnection.java:835)
        at b.e.a.M.f(HubConnection.java:440)
        at b.e.a.M.c(HubConnection.java:309)
        at b.e.a.n.a(lambda)
        at b.e.a.oa.b(WebSocketTransport.java:96)
        at b.e.a.oa.a(WebSocketTransport.java:56)
        at b.e.a.t.a(lambda)
        at b.e.a.ea$a.onClosing(OkHttpWebSocketWrapper.java:89)
        at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.onReadClose(RealWebSocket.java:345)
        at okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader.readControlFrame(WebSocketReader.java:204)
        at okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader.processNextFrame(WebSocketReader.java:99)
        at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.loopReader(RealWebSocket.java:262)
        at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$2.onResponse(RealWebSocket.java:201)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I don't now this error is for signalR or okhttp so I add but in proguard.
here is this 2 in my proguard.

```
##------------------- signalR -----------
-keep class microsoft.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
##--------------- okhttp  —------—
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontnote okhttp3.**

##--------------- Okio  —------—
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fault because I use signalR (not core) before and I added proguard for it

```
-keep class microsoft.** { *; }
```

and I must change this for signalR core and add

```
-keep class com.microsoft.** { *; }
```